# Difference between Database and File Storage in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

> Based on the FAQ at Parse.com:
>
> What is the difference between database storage and file storage?
>   Database storage refers to data stored as Parse Objects, which are
>   limited to 128 KB in size. File storage refers to static assets that
>   are stored using the Parse File APIs, typically images, documents, and
>   other types of binary data.

Just want some clarification here:

So the Strings, Arrays etc created are considered as Parse Objects and would fall under the database storage, also the URL of the file will be considered under the database storage since it is a Parse Object. But the actual files itself are considered under File Storage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any file that you upload to Parse goes to the File storage, the rest is stored in the database including the URL of such files.